# Visual Studio Warning - Prefix 'S_' or 'T_' is not expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naming-conventions, visual-studio-2022

Whenever I create many constants for different purposes in a project, I tend to categorize them by putting a one letter prefix and an underscore in front of the names. Now, I chose the prefix **T_** for some constants and noticed that the compiler gave me a warning:

`IDE1006: Naming rule violation: Prefix 'T_' is not expected`

That made me really curious, since I have no naming rule configured that says anything about that prefix, so I experimented a little. This warning only shows for the letters S and T, both uppercase and lowercase, so other prefixes like **A_**, **b_** or **Z_** are allowed. I tried this with local variables, properties, constants, methods and classes, and for all those cases, this rule applies: No uppercase or lowercase **T_** or **S_** at the start of an identifier. I know there are many cases I didn't test, but I'm pretty sure this is consistent across all sorts of identifiers in C#.

*Now the question is, **why is that**? Are the prefixes **T_**, **t_**, **S_**, **s_** used for anything specific internally, or is it a general naming convention that I simply don't know anything about?*

I already googled for the specific message about the prefix, or the prefix in general, and I also took a very brief look at the documentation of IDE1006. None of those things yielded any answers.

Since it was requested, here's my .editorconfig:

```
[*.cs]

# IDE0039: Use local function
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0039.severity = silent
```

As you can see, there is nothing naming related here.

And here's my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And finally, the .editorconfig file generated from my Code Style settings (naming conventions at the very bottom):

```
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher directories
root = true

# C# files
[*.cs]

#### Core EditorConfig Options ####

# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = 4
indent_style = tab
tab_width = 4

# New line preferences
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = false

#### .NET Coding Conventions ####

# Organize usings
dotnet_separate_import_directive_groups = true
dotnet_sort_system_directives_first = true
file_header_template = unset

# this. and Me. preferences
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:warning
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:warning
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:warning

# Language keywords vs BCL types preferences
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:warning
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:warning

# Parentheses preferences
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_arithmetic_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:suggestion
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:suggestion
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_operators = never_if_unnecessary:suggestion
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_relational_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:suggestion

# Modifier preferences
dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = for_non_interface_members

# Expression-level preferences
dotnet_style_coalesce_expression = true:warning
dotnet_style_collection_initializer = true:warning
dotnet_style_explicit_tuple_names = true:warning
dotnet_style_namespace_match_folder = true
dotnet_style_null_propagation = true:warning
dotnet_style_object_initializer = true:warning
dotnet_style_operator_placement_when_wrapping = beginning_of_line
dotnet_style_prefer_auto_properties = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_compound_assignment = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_assignment = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_return = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_anonymous_type_member_names = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_tuple_names = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_boolean_expressions = true:warning
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_interpolation = true

# Field preferences
dotnet_style_readonly_field = true:warning

# Parameter preferences
dotnet_code_quality_unused_parameters = all:warning

# Suppression preferences
dotnet_remove_unnecessary_suppression_exclusions = none

# New line preferences
dotnet_style_allow_multiple_blank_lines_experimental = true
dotnet_style_allow_statement_immediately_after_block_experimental = true

#### C# Coding Conventions ####

# var preferences
csharp_style_var_elsewhere = false:warning
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = false:warning
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = false:warning

# Expression-bodied members
csharp_style_expression_bodied_accessors = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_constructors = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_indexers = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_lambdas = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_local_functions = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_methods = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_operators = true:warning
csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = true:warning

# Pattern matching preferences
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_as_with_null_check = true:warning
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_is_with_cast_check = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_extended_property_pattern = true
csharp_style_prefer_not_pattern = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_pattern_matching = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_switch_expression = true:warning

# Null-checking preferences
csharp_style_conditional_delegate_call = true:warning

# Modifier preferences
csharp_prefer_static_local_function = true:warning
csharp_preferred_modifier_order = public,private,protected,internal,static,extern,new,virtual,abstract,sealed,override,readonly,unsafe,volatile,async

# Code-block preferences
csharp_prefer_braces = false:warning
csharp_prefer_simple_using_statement = true:warning
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:warning

# Expression-level preferences
csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression = true:warning
csharp_style_deconstructed_variable_declaration = true
csharp_style_implicit_object_creation_when_type_is_apparent = true:warning
csharp_style_inlined_variable_declaration = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_index_operator = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_local_over_anonymous_function = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_null_check_over_type_check = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_range_operator = true:warning
csharp_style_prefer_tuple_swap = true
csharp_style_throw_expression = true:warning
csharp_style_unused_value_assignment_preference = discard_variable:warning
csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = discard_variable

# 'using' directive preferences
csharp_using_directive_placement = outside_namespace:warning

# New line preferences
csharp_style_allow_blank_line_after_colon_in_constructor_initializer_experimental = false:warning
csharp_style_allow_blank_lines_between_consecutive_braces_experimental = true
csharp_style_allow_embedded_statements_on_same_line_experimental = true

#### C# Formatting Rules ####

# New line preferences
csharp_new_line_before_catch = false
csharp_new_line_before_else = false
csharp_new_line_before_finally = false
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = true
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses = true

# Indentation preferences
csharp_indent_block_contents = true
csharp_indent_braces = false
csharp_indent_case_contents = true
csharp_indent_case_contents_when_block = false
csharp_indent_labels = one_less_than_current
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true

# Space preferences
csharp_space_after_cast = true
csharp_space_after_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_after_comma = true
csharp_space_after_dot = false
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = true
csharp_space_after_semicolon_in_for_statement = true
csharp_space_around_binary_operators = before_and_after
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = false
csharp_space_before_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_before_comma = false
csharp_space_before_dot = false
csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_before_semicolon_in_for_statement = false
csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_name_and_opening_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_name_and_open_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_square_brackets = false

# Wrapping preferences
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = false

#### Naming styles ####

# Naming rules

dotnet_naming_rule.constant_should_be_capslock.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_should_be_capslock.symbols = constant
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_should_be_capslock.style = capslock

dotnet_naming_rule.local_should_be_camel_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.local_should_be_camel_case.symbols = local
dotnet_naming_rule.local_should_be_camel_case.style = camel_case

dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.symbols = interface
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.style = begins_with_i

dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = types
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = non_field_members
dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

# Symbol specifications

dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_kinds = interface
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_kinds = class, struct, interface, enum
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_kinds = property, event, method
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.constant.applicable_kinds = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant.required_modifiers = const

dotnet_naming_symbols.local.applicable_kinds = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.local.applicable_accessibilities = local
dotnet_naming_symbols.local.required_modifiers = 

# Naming styles

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_prefix = I
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.capslock.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.capslock.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.capslock.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.capslock.capitalization = all_upper

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization = camel_case
```

---

PS: I know using underscores in identifiers is sort of frowned upon, the reason I use them is because I name my constants in capslock, which, I think, is also frowned upon? I do that because I prefer having a clear indication of what's a constant and what isn't.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a .editorconfig file? If you do, please post it, otherwise the only thing we can say is "You probably **do** have a naming rule which forbids this"

Comment: I believe that the warning is dependent of the current naming rules of a project/solution/machine. Check .editorconfig and other places where code style may be defined.

Comment: @canton7 By "I have nothing configured that says anything about that prefix" I mean my code style settings. If it is defined in the .editorconfig file then the question still stands, why is it defined there? Because I certainly didn't do that myself.

Comment: @Serg Same thing here, sure, it may be defined in .editorconfig, but that doesn't answer why it is there.

Comment: @Nyde I don't follow. .editorconfig is a file which you write. If something is in that file, then you put it there. Ultimately though, for questions which look like "I configured everything so X shoudn't happen, but X does happen", the answer is normally "You probably didn't configure it right. Let us see if we can spot the mistake". If the asker keeps insisting "No everything I did is flawless" but doesn't let us check it, there's not normally anything we can do.

Comment: In this case, @CaiusJard has spotted something which probably explains why the defaults are the way they are, but seeing your config will at least let us repro and play around with the options, whereas right now we're just guessing

Comment: @CaiusJard It wouldn't be. I feel like it's necessary because I know many people on StackOverflow don't seem to understand that people here just want their questions answered. Sure, some people make very questionable choices that are causing their problems, but in my case I am just curious about something. Sure, my own code is what made me aware of the "problem", but it isn't actually a part of it, and I simply wanted to make clear that my own decisions toward coding do not actually have anything to do with my question and I don't want them to be discussed.

Comment: @Nyde The point is not that you said that, but the tone which you said it with.

Comment: @canton7 How is .editorconfig a file I write? I have never touched or even looked at that file, it's just there, auto-generated by Visual Studio. And that's not a VS2022 thing either, I've already seen that with VS2019. Maybe it's empty, I don't know. But if there's something in it, it is definitely auto-generated by Visual Studio, the only thing I have to do with it are my own naming conventions in the code style settings, which, as I said, have nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Nyde So... Why don't you open it, see what's inside, and post it into your question so that we can see, too? Like I said 22 minutes ago. I've never seen one created automatically without *some* user input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239117/discussion-between-canton7-and-nyde).

Comment: I can't replicate this in a new project. I'm not sure why the convention found by @CaiusJard is applying by default: in my understanding, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @canton7 Are you using VS2022 or VS2019? Maybe it's new to 2022

Comment: I have fresh 2022 and there are no such rules configured by default for me.

Comment: That's VS2019 - I can try VS2022 this evening. But I haven't read any indication that VS2022 starts applying arbitrary naming rules by default. Are you sure you don't have StyleCop or similar installed? Can you post your .csproj perhaps -- maybe there's a seemingly-innocuous option there

Comment: @canton7 I am very sure that I have nothing installed on VS2022 that cannot be installed directly alongside it in VS Installer.

Comment: @Nyde StyleCop is added to your project as a NuGet package, not installed by the VS installer

Comment: The only thing I have configured in my code style settings is that I have the severity of naming rule violations set to "Warning". But still, even if I didn't do that, it'd still be there as a quick fix suggestion, it just wouldn't put up emergency signs, lmao. Yeah I think I should have mentioned this earlier

Comment: Where are you finding these "code style settings"? These days, any code style should be written to a .editorconfig, but the .editorconfig you posted doesn't have anything to set the severity of naming rules. Do you have another configuration file you haven't posted? There's another piece to this puzzle, and I'm finding it hard to help you find it

Comment: @canton7 That was what I meant, I never installed anything that I couldn't install through VS Installer

Comment: @Nyde So you don't reference any NuGet packages whatsoever? Just posting your .csproj as I asked would save us a lot of back-and-forth here

Comment: @canton7 Tools / Options / Text Editor / C# / Code Style / Naming. I think the settings in Text Editor / C# are default values that the .editorconfig can merely override.

Comment: Put .csproj into my question

Comment: Thanks. Aha, that UI has improved a lot since I last went there. Can you go to Text Editor -> C#  -> Code Style and click "Generate .editorconfig file from settings", and put that in your question? That will let us see what style rules are being applied, without needing back-and-forth or screenshots, etc

Comment: I'm also not sure whether things like those code style settings are synced with your account - so it would be interesting to compare what you have with what our defaults are

Comment: @canton7 Added Code Style settings

Comment: And yeah, I changed a lot of my Code Style settings. I am really pedantic about the formatting of my code, and the problem is that I originally came from Java years ago so I think that shows haha

Comment: Thanks. You have the rules constant_should_be_capslock and local_should_be_camel_case which I don't have -- not sure whether that's you or VS2022, @Evk can you help? I'm failing to square "*The only thing I have configured in my code style settings is that I have the severity of naming rule violations set to "Warning"*" with "*And yeah, I changed a lot of my Code Style settings*" -- they seem to be saying opposite things?

Comment: [This appears to be the line](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a2d72621afba6286cc7922435c09cce882fc0b8/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Compiler/Core/NamingStyles/NamingStyle.cs#L188) which raises your error. This was introduced [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26566)

Comment: With your extra rules I can repro this issue.

Comment: @canton7 The "constant should be capslock" are me, the "local should be camel case" are default I'm pretty sure. / The first statement you refer to, that I only changed the severity of that one thing, was badly phrased, sorry. I mean the only thing that could directly relate to the question.

Comment: @canton7 Maybe check if the suggestion to remove the prefix shows up in your quick fix list with your own defaults? As I mentioned earlier in the other comments, It may just be more obvious in my case because I have warnings on.

Comment: Please remember you're not in a position to decide what is and isn't relevant to the question. If you knew, you wouldn't be asking it. In fact, that "capslock" rule **is** the cause of this -- I don't think it *should* be causing it, but that rule is critical in reproducing it. By not mentioning it, you wasted time and effort.

Comment: No, the IDE1006 only fires when you have a rule which applies to the const -- it's fired as a result of (mis)-processing that rule

Comment: @canton7 I just removed the capslock rule entirely and created a new project. I can still reproduce it.

Comment: I do think this is a bug in the naming rule handling -- it's taking a naming which you've said is separated by underscores, and deciding that a single character `m`, `s` or `t` before the first underscore is a prefix. Since your rule also says there are no expected prefixes, it's throwing a warning

Comment: @Nyde Do you have *any* rules which apply to consts? I don't think it has to be an `all_caps` rule specifically, it just needs *a* rule which applies to that type of symbol

Comment: @canton7 I removed the naming rule for Constants entirely. The only thing left that COULD refer to constants is, funnily, the "local" naming rule, because it refers to everything as long as its scope is local. I just removed that too, restarted VS2022, created a new project, and I can still reproduce it.

Comment: Just did another check, I removed ALL my naming rules, restarted VS, created a new project, and it still gives me that warning.

Comment: You've gone through the process of generating a new .editorconfig using "Generate .editorconfig file from settings", and confirmed that the result is empty?

Comment: @canton7 Literally just did as you posted the comment. It is empty. Funnily, though, I still get warnings that apply from my old naming rules, even in the newly created projects???

Comment: (Like, the .editorconfig is not empty, but all naming related sections are)

Comment: Did you notice my idea, "Maybe check if the suggestion to remove the prefix shows up in your quick fix list with your own defaults?" Because since I have warnings on, it might just show up for you but not as a warning or something

Comment: Yes I checked that, and no it didn't appear. From the Roslyn code in my answer it's fairly clear that this is applies when checking to see whether a name meets a rule, anyway: if there's no rule, that code won't run

Comment: Okay, I just loaded up my previous project, and now the deleted rules don't apply anymore. So now no naming rules are applied anymore, and the T_ prefix warning doesn't happen either, not even as a suggestion. When I applied the constant rule again, the prefix warning also showed up. So turns out you were right. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug with the naming rule code, and I've [opened an issue with Roslyn here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/57706).

The problem happens when you have a naming rule which applies to your consts (although I suspect the exact type of symbol doesn't matter). The code which checks that a name meets a rule is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a2d72621afba6286cc7922435c09cce882fc0b8/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Compiler/Core/NamingStyles/NamingStyle.cs#L157). It's fine up to [this section](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a2d72621afba6286cc7922435c09cce882fc0b8/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Compiler/Core/NamingStyles/NamingStyle.cs#L181):

```
name = StripCommonPrefixes(name.Substring(Prefix.Length), out var prefix);

if (prefix != string.Empty)
{
    // name started with specified prefix, but has at least one additional common prefix 
    // Example: specified prefix "test_", actual prefix "test_m_"
    failureReason = Prefix == string.Empty ?
        string.Format(CompilerExtensionsResources.Prefix_0_is_not_expected, prefix) :
        string.Format(CompilerExtensionsResources.Prefix_0_does_not_match_expected_prefix_1, prefix, Prefix);
    return false;
}
```

(`Prefix_0_is_not_expected` is the "Prefix '{0}' is not expected" [error message](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/315c2e149ba7889b0937d872274c33fcbfe9af5f/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Compiler/Core/CompilerExtensionsResources.resx#L237) you're seeing, which is how I found this code.)

`StripCommonPrefixes` looks [like this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a2d72621afba6286cc7922435c09cce882fc0b8/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Compiler/Core/NamingStyles/NamingStyle.cs#L377):

```
public static string StripCommonPrefixes(string name, out string prefix)
{
    var index = 0;
    while (index + 1 < name.Length)
    {
        switch (char.ToLowerInvariant(name[index]))
        {
            case 'm':
            case 's':
            case 't':
                if (index + 2 < name.Length && name[index + 1] == '_')
                {
                    index += 2;
                    continue;
                }

                break;

            case '_':
                index++;
                continue;

            default:
                break;
        }

        // If we reach this point, the current iteration did not strip any additional characters
        break;
    }

    prefix = name.Substring(0, index);
    return name.Substring(index);
}
```

If it finds that the name starts with `m_`, `s_` or `t_` (in any casing) with any number of leading underscores, it determines that it's a "prefix". Since we didn't configure a prefix, and it found one, we get a warning.

This is why you found the rule only fires with `S_` and `T_` (you missed `M_`).

However, I don't see how this code can reliably determine what is a prefix and what isn't given that our name is supposed to contain underscores, which is why I raised it as an issue.

When this code was [originally introduced](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/26589/files#diff-75782740d092fb25fc668f470733607c78dab36f6206a270c4093e87602a59ef), it just stripped common prefixes from the name. This was [changed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/32549/files#diff-75782740d092fb25fc668f470733607c78dab36f6206a270c4093e87602a59ef) in Jan 2019, apparently with unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the prefixes T_, t_, S_, s_ used for anything specific

Quote the [coding conventions manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions):

> When working with `static` fields that are `private` or `internal`, use the `s_` prefix and for thread static use `t_`.
>
> ```
> public class DataService
> {
>    private static IWorkerQueue s_workerQueue;
>
>    [ThreadStatic]
>    private static TimeSpan t_timeSpan;
> }
> ```

Comment: Don't think it answers the question. That's just an example of coding style, but I doubt it's enforced by default in visual studio. I for example can't reproduce the problem described by OP (unless I go and create this naming convention by hand).

Comment: *Don't think it answers the question* - I quoted the question I was answering; you're free to post an alternative answer if you like?

Comment: "Are the prefixes T_, t_, S_, s_ used for anything specific internally" < they aren't used "internally", you just linked to arbitrary code style guideline which might or might not be used. The question is why OP sees that warning while he seemingly did not explicitly configured anything to use this naming style.

Comment: The reason I say this is because it may look like (from your answer) that coding style is somehow "default" or built-in in VIsual Studio or something, while it's not.

Comment: @Evk apparently it is, as you can see in the comments of the question. I installed nothing and configured nothing regarding that convention, I only changed the Severity of generally all naming rule violations to "Warning" which does not change the fact that that rule is somehow built into VS2022

Comment: @Nyde I also have fresh 2022 installed yesterday and do not have this problem. Try to create completely new solution and project in that solution and see if that also has this issue.

Comment: @Evk Already did, even in a completely new solution this still applies.

Comment: @Evk I don't see where I used the word *internally*; stop inventing "problems" and taking issue with them. Please post your own answer if you want to respond to something specific.

Comment: To satisfy everyone: This perfectly answered my question about the "why does this exist". The only question left now (which is however not the one I asked) is, why does this happen for me but not for anyone else? Maybe check if it shows up as a quick fix suggestion or anything. As I said, I have naming rule violations generally set up as warnings, so maybe it's just more obvious in my case than in yours.

Comment: @Nyde I'd urge caution when editing questions; it should not be done so as to drastically change the question being asked and invalidate existing answers; it has a tendency to result in this kind of "but this answer doesn't answer the question". If you ask a question and it gets you an answer that leads to a new question, a whole new question should be asked and the old question left, that way it doesn't result in a sequence of goalpost shifts that force *everyone* to keep everything in sync

Comment: @CaiusJard I didn't edit my question, I don't know what you mean?

Comment: *The only question left now (which is however not the one I asked) is, why does this happen for me but not for anyone else?* - this is a goalpost shift. It should be posed as a new question so that it can get the correct attention it requires

Comment: The question just lacked details to be properly answered, that's why there are 30 comments under it trying to clarify.

Comment: @CaiusJard I just said that this is still something that's being wondered about, but I still didn't edit my question...